# Avoid form Submit on client

Tags: c#, javascript, xslt, mootools

I am trying to figure it out how to prevent a form submission if a button type submit return false. This is my code. I just want to prevent a postback if the the input text is empty.

```
      <form action="{$action}" id="home-search-form-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group">
             <input class="form-control" id="pal" type="text"/>
              <button type="submit" value="" onclick="return empty();" id="btn-search"/>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    var btnsearch = $('btnsearch');
    btnsearch.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        empty();
    });

    function empty() {
        var searchInput = $('pal');
        alert(searchInput.get('text'));
        if (searchInput.get('text') == "") {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

EDITED

```
$('home-search-form-form').submit(function () {
    return empty();
});


function empty() {
    var searchInput = $('pal');

    alert(searchInput.get('text'));
    if (searchInput.get('text') == "") {
        // Show some error to the user,
        return false;
    }
    return true; // Changed here...
}
```

Comment: I would really add this onsubmit of the form rather than onclick of the button, otherwise someone could fill out your text field, hit enter, which will submit the form without clicking the button, and bypass your validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a listener for the submit event and you have to access the value, inputs do not have text:

```
$('home-search-form-form').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
    var searchInput = $('pal');

    if (searchInput.get('value') == "") {
        // Show some error to the user
        e.stop();
        return;
    }

    // everything ok, continue submission
});
```

Like Dimitar said, just stop the event if validation fails.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqqf/)

By the way, your HTML is invalid. You are closing a *div* which was never opened.

Answer (score 1):

Also **remove** the `onclick` handler from HTML because you are already attaching an event using jQuery/javaScript -

`<button type="submit" value="" onclick="return empty();" id="btn-search"/>`

change to -

`<button type="submit" value="" id="btn-search"/>`

Return the result of calling the `empty()` function;

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        var btnsearch = $('#btnsearch');  // Added #
        btnsearch.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            return empty(); // Changed here...
        });

        function empty() {
            var searchInput = $('pal');
            alert(searchInput.get('text'));
            if (searchInput.get('text') == "") {
                // Show some error to the user,
                return false;
            }
            return true; // Changed here...
        }        
    });
```

If you are using jQuery, you should probably write this code instead --

```
    $(function(){
        $('#btnSearch').click(function(){
            return empty();
        })

        function empty() {
            var searchInput = $('pal');
            alert(searchInput.get('text'));
            if (searchInput.get('text') == "") {
                // Show some error to the user,
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    })
```

**EDIT -**

As suggested by @Tom, I agree that adding it to the **form's submit event** is always a better choice. Please try this code -

```
$(function(){
        $('#home-search-form-form').submit(function(){
            return empty();
        });

        function empty() {
            var searchInput = $('pal');
            alert(searchInput.get('text'));
            if (searchInput.get('text') == "") {
                // Show some error to the user,
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }    
    })
```

Comment: I am ussing mootools, I tried with the before code and still do a postback :(

Comment: I already did but automatically redirect to the next page if i made a submit to the form.

Comment: If you are using mootools and not jQuery, you should update the question and tag it with mootools.

Comment: er. the mootools code should bind to the form's submit and not the button's click - you can submit a form by pressing enter. work with the `event` - it gets passed in. `if (validationFailed) event.stop();`, do not return false.

Comment: could you explain it a little more plz?